# Adding Value to TextArea from Two Lists. The Two Lists should not be able to add values amongst themselfs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have the following :

1) Text Area with the id="To"

```
@Html.TextArea("To", new { id = "To", @style = "height: 40px; width:100%;border:1px solid black", @class = ".connectedSortable" })
```

2) List of users with the id "sortable1"

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
```

3)List of groups with the id "sortable2"

```
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
```

[image]

When i try to add value from "sortable1" to "To" it works ok . When i try to add Value from "sortable2" to "To" it works ok. 
When i try to add value from "sortable1" to "sortable2" it works ok , although it shouldn't. Considering the fact that i need both lists to have same class as " To" , how can i avoid them trading elements ?

Here is the JQuery code for the connection between the elements :

```
  $("#sortable1, #To").sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();

        $("#sortable2, #To").sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Why do the 2 lists need to use connectedSortable? Couldn't you just make a new class that they use?

Comment: I need both of them to be connected with my Textarea. Im building a string List and the connection is done through the class of the textarea which is unique. Thus the only way ( i know how ) to connect my lists is through that class

Comment: Maess , make that into an answer. I thought that the list and the textare have to have the same class. I was mistaken . Thanks for the help. It solved my problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do the 2 lists need to use connectedSortable? Couldn't you just make a new class that they use?

Comment: Made into an answer at the request of the OP.